# Redis on Windows - config file

Tags: redis

I have just installed redis server on Windows from [here](https://github.com/rgl/redis) and ran the server in default mode with no config file specified.

How do I link the config file (using Windows) to the server and how do I specify the folder to save the dtb in?

The folder looks like this:

- folder: C:\Program Files\Redis\conf - there is some template conf file
- folder: C:\Program Files\Redis\data - empty
- folder: C:\Program Files\Redis\logs - empty
- file:   C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-server.exe
- file:   C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-cli.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need to do is to run the redis-server.exe followed by the filename of your config file.

eg:

```
D:\Coding\RedisIO>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf
```

And for the db file you need to add / change the line in the config file:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb
```

and below of that in the config file the entry

```
# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
# 
# The Append Only File and the QFork memory mapped file will also be created 
# inside this directory.
# 
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
# 
# The Append Only File and the QFork memory mapped file will also be created 
# inside this directory.
# 
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir ./
```

Comment: when i run D:\Coding\Redis>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf , console goes to sleep. Nothing happens , as if it is waiting for some instruction.

Comment: It's quite some years ago that I worked with redis but currently I would think that your server is running and waiting for connection. Did you try to connect to your local redis db?

Answer (score 4):

You may have installed Redis 3.2.100 from (https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases).
But this gave me the errors.

To fix that, download Redis 5.0.9 from (https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases). Run this server, and you'll be good.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed Redis using the MSI package, then Redis was already installed as a Windows service. If you would like to change its settings, you can update the redis.windows-service.conf file found in your installation folder and then restart the Redis service (Run -> services.msc -> Redis -> Restart).

For more detailed instructions, please follow the documentation provided in your installation folder with the name as **Windows Service Documentation.docx**